# Convering json data to Java script array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have code above which gets data from a database and then place in in json form to make it readable in java script.
 the results of the echo is 
"FIAT":["Anglia","Bronco","Capri","Cobra","Consul","Corsair","Cortina"],

"Land Rover":["Defender","Discovery","Discovery 3","Discovery 4"] 
I would like the data to be converted in such a way the i can reference it in this form Var Brand=array ();

Brand["FIAT"]=["Anglia","Bronco","Capri","Cobra","Consul","Corsair","Cortina"];

Brand["Land Rover"]=["Defender","Discovery","Discovery 3","Discovery 4"];

in java script. Does Any one know how i can do this.

$query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `car_models`");

// Loop the DB result
while(($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query))) {

```
// Check if this ID is already in the data array
if(!array_key_exists($result['Brand'], $data)){

    // Create array for current user
    $data[$result['Brand']] = array();

}

// Add the current race time to the array (do not need to use the float)
```

$data[$result['Brand']][] = $result['Model'];

}

//json data
json_encode($data);

Comment: You're now just doing PHP, right? If you want to output it to Javascript, the cleanest way is to create an Restfull API call. You can use JQuery, Angular or any other JS framework to fetch the PHP array to your Javascript code.

Comment: The code above seems is your PHP producing the JSON object, right? How  do you fetch it from JS, then?

Comment: yes thats my php .... am kind of new to java script or jQuery.. would appreciate some help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Simply added the json object in a variable and now am able to get the echo it to the console

`
 //json data
var brandAvailable =  
console.log(brandAvailable);

"`